What is the Kingdom of Heaven?
In Matt 7:21 the Textus Receptus uses the word for heaven in two different ways, can one be physical and the other spiritual?
Textus Receptus (Beza 1598):

ου πας ο λεγων μοι κυριε κυριε εισελευσεται εις την βασιλειαν των ουρανων αλλ ο ποιων το θελημα του πατρος μου του εν ουρανοις


Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Welcome to the BH forum, William. Be sure to take the tour. Regarding your question,  Johnathan Pennington published his PhD thesis as an entire book on this subject, Heaven and Earth in the Gospel of Matthew. Obviously, his book is not a light read, but it's thorough and technical. Note that the word is always in the plural in Hebrew and usually plural in the Greek for grammatical reasons. Jesus introduces the term, kingdom of the heavens, in the New Testament. The answers below are excellent!

A good check in cases like this is to consult a large number of translations and see how they render it, and also to consult commentaries. If your translation idea stands alone, that’s a red flag that it might be incorrect and definitely requires careful investigation on your part. If there’s agreement with a decent number of respected translations and/or commentaries, that lends credence to the feasibility of your translation idea, even though it doesn’t prove it one way or another.

I suggest this because it’s very very easy to read into the Greek or Hebrew what isn’t there through translation error, and consulting the work of those who came before you is a good check on your translation work to help you catch those errors before they become theological or doctrinal errors.

There's really two main usages of the word. Strong's gives the usages as so:

Usage: heaven, (a) the visible heavens: the atmosphere, the sky, the
starry heavens, (b) the spiritual heavens.

Both uses of “ουρανος” refer to the spiritual heaven. However, in context, they specify different aspects:

The kingdom of heaven is more about the spiritual realm and the reign
of God.
The Father in heaven is more locational. Where God
resides. So, in this context, to us, one appears as more spiritual (the
kingdom of heaven) and the other as more physical (the dwelling place
of God), though both are ultimately spiritual.


Thayer's Greek Lexicon gives a bit more detail on the word:

The vaulted expanse of the sky with all the things visible in it:

Generally:

As opposed to the earth (e.g., Hebrews 1:10; 2 Peter 3:5, 10, 12).
Equivalent to the universe or the world (e.g., Genesis 1:1; Matthew
5:18; Acts 4:24).


The aerial heavens or sky:

The region where clouds and tempests gather, and where thunder and
lightning are produced (e.g., Matthew 16:2; James 5:18).




The region above the sidereal heavens, the seat of an order of things
eternal and consummately perfect, where God dwells and the other
heavenly beings:

a. The highest heaven:

The dwelling place of God (e.g., Matthew 5:34; Acts 7:49).
The abode of angels and the place from which the Holy Spirit is sent
down (e.g., Matthew 3:16; John 1:32).
The future abode of those who are raised from the dead and clothed with superior bodies (e.g., 2 Corinthians 5:1; Matthew 5:12).


b. Expressions related to divine authority:

“ἐκ τοῦ οὐρανοῦ” (from heaven) equivalent to “by God” (e.g., John 3:27).
“ἐξ οὐρανοῦ” (of divine authority) (e.g., Matthew 21:25).






First, here is my (overly) literal translation of Matt 7:21 (the Greek text is undisputed):

Not all who say to Me, "Lord, Lord", will enter into the kingdom of
the heavens; but the one doing the will of My Father, who is in the
heavens

I am not sure that, especially in view of Jesus' teaching in John 3, that the two instances of οὐρανός ("heaven") are used in a different sense here.  I think both designate the same thing, namely: the origin of the spiritual dimension which is also

the origin of Jesus (John 3:13, 6:38, 41, 42, 51, 1 Cor 15:47, 48, 49, etc)
the origin and seat of the Father (Matt 3:17, 6:9, 18:14, 23:9, Mark 1:11, 11:2, Luke 3:22, 11;2, John 12:28, 2 Peter 1:18, etc)
Jesus is the king of this heavenly kingdom who is now on the throne of the heavenly kingdom, Matt 26:64, Mark 14:62, 16:19, Luke 22:69, Acts 2:33, 7:55, 56, Rom 8:34, Col 3:1, Heb 1:3, 8:1, 10:12, 12:2, 1 Peter 3:22, etc.
As King of the heavenly kingdom, Jesus governs the kingdom of heaven including those citizens of the kingdom of heaven still on earth (ie, Christians) via His Holy Spirit who is also from heaven (Mark 1:10, Acts 1:2, Heb 6:4, 1 Peter 1:12, etc)
the place from which earthly citizens of heaven are "born" (Matt 5:45, 19:45, Luke 6:35, John 3:3, 7 "=born from above", Heb 12:23, etc)
the origin of the New Jerusalem, the home of the saved (Rev 3:12, 21:2, 10
and thus, quite correctly the origin of the "Kingdom of Heaven"

Thus, the title "kingdom of Heaven" emphasizes several things:

the heavenly origin of this kingdom
the heavenly government of this kingdom
the distinction between this heavenly kingdom and all other earthly (and transitory) kingdoms
the fact that all God's saved long to be in this heavenly kingdom as per Heb 3:1, 11:16.


@ Dottard - Add also that the kingdom suffers violence and people are pressing into it...that there must be a spiritual rebirth to enter it...that it comes without observation...and we must conclude what you just concluded! Good answer!

For the purpose of this answer, I will take the word 'kingdom' to be key. This is because the correct sense of what a kingdom is applies equally to either a literal or a spiritual kingdom, and once that is established, matters should fall more easily into place.
A kingdom requires a king, and that which the king rules over. The location is secondary to there being subjects over which the king rules. That is because there need not be actual land, an actual location, for legitimate rulership of a king over his subjects. Both could be in exile, removed from the land. Both could be in a realm that is not physical, earthly.
Matthew 7:21, the Textus Receptus, substantiates this point:

"Not everyone who is saying to me, Lord, lord, shall come into the
reign of the heavens; but he who is doing the will of my Father who is
in the heavens." Young's Literal Translation

Note how Jesus speaks of the reign of the heavens ? And he identifies two groups of people on the Day of Judgment, one being deluded into supposing they are accepted by the King (the Lord of lords), therefore having him reign over them prior to the Day of Judgment, the other truly being subjects of the Father who is in the heavens. Jesus says the former group are cast away from him as workers of lawlessness. Therefore, not subjects of the King, for they do not have this One to reign over them no matter how much they protest to the contrary.
The question, "What is the Kingdom of Heaven?" can be understood by those who truly have the King of Heaven reign over them, while on Earth before they die physically. That experience will continue without a blip when they find themselves in the heavenly presence of their King. This means that 'entrance' into the Kingdom of Heaven is spiritual, for there is no literal kingdom here on Earth that can be identified as the Kingdom of Heaven, but once subjects find themselves in heaven, the glory of that Kingdom will be experienced to a phenomenal degree.
As Jesus said, it is coming into the reign of the heavens - now - that determines continuation of heaven's reign over God's children. Those children who have bent their knee in Jesus' name and acclaim him to be King of kings and Lord of lords experience the reality of the invisible kingdom now, and that will continue in an immeasurably enhanced experience in heaven.

Yes, indeed. 'Going to heaven' should better be rendered 'entering into the kingdom of the heavens'. Up-voted +1.


… uses the word for heaven in two different ways, can one be physical and the other spiritual?

Yes (though in this case they are both used the same way).
Consider 2 Corinthians 12:2:

I knew a man in Christ above fourteen years ago, (whether in the body, I cannot tell; or whether out of the body, I cannot tell: God knoweth;) such an one caught up to the third heaven.

Paul uses the term "third heaven" to refer to God's spiritual abode.
The first heaven is the Earth's atmosphere (clouds, birds, weather, etc.).
The second heaven is what we call outer space.
(In many languages the word for sky has both physical and spiritual meanings, with context determining what is meant.
For instance, both in French "le ciel", and in Chinese "tiān, 天", can mean either sky or Heaven.
The famous "Tiān'ānmén, 天安门" is three words: "heaven", "peace", and "gate"; which together indicate that "heaven" has its spiritual meaning: gate of heavenly peace.)
In the case of Matthew 7:21:

Not every one that saith unto me, Lord, Lord, shall enter into the kingdom of heaven; but he that doeth the will of my Father which is in heaven.

The second use, "in heaven", clearly refers to God's spiritual abode.
The first use, "kingdom of heaven" refers to a kingdom originating in God's heaven.
The other three Gospels use the term "kingdom of God" for the same purpose.
The Gospel of Matthew was intended for a Jewish audience, so the term "heaven" is used here rather than "God", because when speaking to Jews it is best to avoid direct references to God unless they are essential.

What is the Kingdom of Heaven?

The various denominations have many conflicting interpretations of what "Kingdom of God" means, but a literal reading of the Bible indicates that it will be a kingdom established here on Earth, run by Christ and the resurrected saints (the elect), for a thousand years (the Millennium).

@ Ray Butterworth Did not the Lord Jesus begin His ministry saying "the Kingdom is at hand in the first century?  It cannot be, therefore,  a Kingdom in the nebulous future! Is not Jesus King now? What is a king without a kingdom?

@raygrant, "the Kingdom is at hand" is the ESV translation, with a footnote: "Or the kingdom of God has come near". The primary meaning of G932 is "royal power, kingship, dominion, rule, not to be confused with an actual kingdom but rather the right or authority to rule over a kingdom". So, "the royal power of God has come near", with Jesus referring to his own presence, is perhaps a better translation, except for those that want it to mean something completely different. Compare with Luke 17:21: would Jesus say that the kingdom is inside the Pharisees, or that the king is among them?
